# Excel VBA code to exclude duplicates from if statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, conditional-statements, duplicates

I am a beginner in Excel VBA. I just want to know how to make this code exclude duplicates in column A. I am not sure which code to write that would exclude duplicates.

I only want to highlight the row if it's not a duplicate.

I hope you can help me. Thank you.

```vb
Sub Test2()

Dim count, i As Long

count = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
i = 2

Do While i <= count

    If Cells(i, 3).Value Like "Expired" Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 98, 76)
    
    ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value Like "New" Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.Color = RGB(118, 234, 62)
    
    End If
    
    i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Btw, you can do this easily with conditional formatting, no need for VBA.

Comment: Where is your picture?

Answer (score 0):

- `Cells(i, 3).Value Like "New"` is same as `Cells(i, 3).Value = "New"`.
- If you want to use case insensitive comparison, try `If StrComp(Cells(i, 3).Value, "New", vbTextCompare)=0 Then`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test2()
    Dim count as Long, i As Long
    count = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    i = 2
    Do While i <= count
        If Application.CountIf(Columns(1), Cells(i, 1)) = 1 Then
            If Cells(i, 3).Value Like "Expired" Then
                Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 98, 76)
            ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value Like "New" Then
                Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.Color = RGB(118, 234, 62)
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

---

- Conditional Formatting is an option too.
- CF formulas

```
=AND($C2="New",COUNTIF($A:$A,$A2)=1)
=AND($C2="Expired",COUNTIF($A:$A,$A2)=1)
```

[image]